# Problems sending data over serial port with PuTTY

Tags: putty, serial-port, hyperterminal

I am using version 0.63 on Windows 7 x64 in a corporate domain environment.

I have an end user that is programming a Bluetooth module over a serial connection. He is using a USB-to-serial adapter, and we had tested it directly on the serial port and the same issue results. We also tried rebooting the device while attached and text does appear, but it appears that when we send text, the device isn't receiving or accepting it.

They used to use HyperTerminal under Windows XP.

It is on COM5, baud rate is 38400, data bits is 8, stop bits is 1, parity is none and flow control is none.

These settings were identical to HyperTerminal.

In HyperTerminal, we also had to enable send line ends with line feeds, echo typed characters locally, append line feeds to incoming line ends, force incoming to 7-bit ASCII, and wrap lines that exceed terminal width.

In PuTTY we tried to emulate that by enabling force on local echo, and implicit CR/LF options.

Far as I can tell, all those settings are correct, however, in PuTTY, the characters do echo, nothing responds. If I were to type in say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, the version of the modules firmware should respond. In PuTTY, nothing gets responded.

It seems there is an error when it is TX.

So, unless there is some other magical setting I am not aware of, is this a bug?
If there is a ht to PuTTY settings conversion process, perhaps that feature can be very useful, especially if I can just double click their saved ht files. So does that exist?

Any ideas as I am getting frustrated as we have no other problems using PuTTY for serial connections for other devices.